# Origen y diferenciación de Hábito (comportamiento), Hábito (religioso) y Habito (Habitar)

Tags: etimología

Cómo estas palabras:

> **Hábito** refiriéndose a comportamiento
>
> **Hábito** refiriéndose a religioso
>
> **Habito** refiriéndose a habitar

surgieron y su significado se diferenció.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como puedes ver en su entrada al wiktionary http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habitus#Latin vienen del verbo tener *habeo*.

Están las 3 palabras que buscas:

- Esta la forma derivada *habitus* (nombre) como definición de comportamiento, conducta (*physical or emotional condition, manner, behaviour*). *Habitus* es el resultado de *habeo* y el sufijo *-tus*
- *Habitare* es el infinitivo presente activo de [*habito*](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/habito) en la definición de donde resido, me alojo habitualmente. *Habito* es el resultado de *habeo* y el sufijo *-ito*.
- De la vestimenta religiosa, se originó de *habitus*(nombre) participio pasivo del verbo [*habere*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habere). Definición: Lo que uno tiene, manera de vestir, por eso en el caso que los monjes es su hábito.